# How to handle a large number of 'using' statements?

Tags: c++, using

Is there an etiquette for dealing with a large number of *using* statements in C++? For example if I have a header file with the following:

```
using std::vector;
using std::string;
...
using std::map;
...
```

where *...* indicate further extensions of *using* statement. I would like a way to reduce 'clutter'. Or is it just bad practice to have a large number of *using* statements?

Comment: It is just "bad practice" to remove the namspace from stl components. There are good reasons to have a long list of aliases, but not for hiding the information, that you want to use stl components without naming them! Simply use std::xxx in your code to clarify that your used identifier comes from the given namespace. If you *really* want to avoid std:: upfront, you simple can use `using namespace std`, but that is also bad practice but avoids long list of alias declarations.

Comment: Yes, thanks I am aware of that. I used STL just as an example. I am really using my own components mainly for error handling and I have many error codes I am attempting to use. Thanks for your answer comment though. @Klaus

Comment: If you're `using` many things, it could be a sign that your application is poorly factored and lacking meaningful abstractions.

Comment: @molbdnilo They are all error codes I have in a header file that I want to use in an error handler which is separate.

Comment: Stick them in their own namespace and say `using namespace errror_codes` (or whatever) in the error handler. You can have using-directives locally in a function.

Comment: The `using namespace std;` is discouraged because `std` is very large, and can change in the future (usually due to adding new things).  Your own namespaces in your own project are under your own control.  I'd still discourage carte blanche `using namespace glc;` in a *header*, but in a source file is *okay* (it'd pass code review on my team) or in the scope of a function is *just fine*.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, exactly, I don't know why I didn't think of something that obvious. Thank you.

Comment: @Eljay ok good to know, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle them is to not use them in namespace scope. You can use qualified names like this for example:

```
std::vector an_example {1, 2, 3};
```